# Instantiate SP.FieldUrlValue fails with "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: 2013, javascript, splistitem, url, jsom

I am trying to change the values of `SP.FieldUrlValue` in a list on SharePoint 2013. The goal is to add thumbnail of some images to the image field of my list based on the name of the title field.

I have added this code as an script to the Dispform.aspx:

```
var fvalue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
fvalue.set_url("Url");
fvalue.set_description("Description");
newListItem.set_item("Image", fvalue);
```

But it seems that the `SP.FieldUrlValue()` function is not defined:

> Uncaught TypeError: SP.FieldUrlValue is not a function.

I have changed the code to :

```
function updateImageItem(){ 
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);  
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Rooms');  
   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
   this.newListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

   var fvalue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
   fvalue.set_url(imgThumbnail);
   fvalue.set_description(roomValue);
   newListItem.set_item('Image', fvalue);

   newListItem.update();  
   clientContext.load(newListItem);  
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),   
     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  

   };  function onQuerySucceeded() {
    SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Item created: ' + newListItem.get_id());
 }

 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

### No errors now, but nothing also happens!

the variables are receiving the link and the description correctly, but still the Image field is empty (it should show the thumbnail). should I add something to the html part as well? to show the image? (I'm new to this era, if the question sounds stupid!)

Comment: SP.js is not loaded by default on every page; you may force a load yourself.

Comment: How i can force it??

Comment: By typing *"force load sp.js"* in Google... or Bing.. or Yahoo

Comment: one more question, it seems that the newListItem.set_item("Image", fvalue) also does not defined as well. what am i missing??

Comment: If this really all your code you miss about 5 lines more JavaScript. Search for **JSOM Update ListItem**

Comment: @dannyEngelman that was a good hint!.now the code looks like this. no error but nothing happens!

Comment: So, add ``console.log`` statements everywhere in your code and use F12 Developer Tools so see where it goes wrong... Its 60% of the programmers daily workload

Comment: @dannyEngelman your answers are really helpful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SP.FieldUrlValue object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245305.aspx) is declared in [`sp.js`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246996.aspx) SharePoint library, this error apparently happens since the specified library is not yet loaded when the specified code is executed.

You could utilize [`SP.SOD.executeFunc` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) to ensure that the specified library is loaded like the shown below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

     var fvalue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
     //...

});
```